# Lightbox for website image viewing with navigation in two dimensions

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox, web-frontend, photo-gallery

- First axis for navigating photo sets (i.e. up/down)
- Other axis for navigating photos within sets (i.e. left/right)

***Does someone know a readymade solution for this? (For Wordpress?)***

#### Use cases: Presentation of screenshots series with a two dimensional nature

- **Responsive Web Design**: Dimension device size (Mobile, Tablet, Laptop, Desktop) with other dimension page (home, products, services, contact)
- **Multi Platform Software**: Dimension software platform (Mac, Linux, Windows) with other dimension use case (open file, do action X, save file)
- **Visual Version History**: Dimension version (Mac OS 7, Mac OS 9, Mac OS X 10.1, macOS 11) with other dimension use case (Open file, Browse folder, Default text editor, Restart computer)

[image: 2-axial lightbox]

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronized Sliders** — Not exactly what I asked for but could achieve a similar UX

Here's a [howto](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-portfolio-image-carousel-with-synchronized-sliders-on-a-web-page) and it's [demo](https://lmgonzalves.github.io/momentum-slider/portfolio-carousel/). *Note*: What's synchronized here is an image-nr, image-text, image-container, but that could easily be i.e. 3 image-containers (on top on smaller screens, in one layout row on larger screens).

Answer (score 0):

**Slider which moves multiple slides per prev/next click**

i.e. http://splidejs.com/#multiple-slides-example

Just set the amount of slides to move to be exactly your amount of photo sets (i.e. your 3 platforms Mac/Linux/Windows) and make sure to fill in blank/pseudo pictures for images which are inexistent (i.e. use case "Restart" missing for Linux).